# Check system requirement before install

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I want to check system requirements(Graphic memory Ram and ...) before start install process and if device is not compatible show warning to user.

Is there any way to do this by inno-setup scripts?

Answer (score 4):

You can use standard Windows APIs to do whatever checks you want to make.

As for how to report it to the user, there are a few different options depending on how you want to present it.

One approach is to put your testing code in the `InitializeSetup` event function; if it fails, display a `MsgBox` telling the user what the problem is, and optionally return `False` to abort the installation.

Another approach is to put your code in the `InitializeWizard` event function and create a custom page (eg. via `CreateOutputMsgMemoPage`, or something completely custom) to report the problems detected -- but only when there actually is a problem.  You can then choose to disable the Next button when the page activates if you want to prevent the user from proceeding with the installation.

Both approaches are perfectly valid; which one you should go with simply depends on how you want to present the issue to the user, which may in turn depend on how many things you are checking, how "serious" they are, and whether you want to display some additional information or not.

Comment: tnx, but I don't know how to check whether VGA type or memory is compatible (and enough) or not.